# how to print remaining portion of each line after a pattern match using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed, grep, cygwin

I have the following text in my file.

```
log-2023-06-30-082821.txt:2023-06-30 08:30:32.648
log-2023-06-30-082821.txt:2023-06-30 08:32:07.235
log-2023-06-30-083220.txt:2023-06-30 08:32:55.831
log-2023-06-30-083604.txt:2023-06-30 08:36:39.380
```

I want to print the rest of the portion of each line as soon as there is a pattern match ':'.
The output should look like this.

```
2023-06-30 08:30:32.648
2023-06-30 08:32:07.235
2023-06-30 08:32:55.831
2023-06-30 08:36:39.380
```

How can I do this using sed. I am using Cygwin in Windows. I tried a bunch of sed patterns but they haven't worked.

Comment: (learn to use the `{}` tool from the **Edit** menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Glad you got some solutions. Good luck!

Comment: AND ... rather than say *"but they haven't worked."* be sure to include what you think should have worked in the body of your question (not as a comment! (-;!) .. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single character, you can use it as a field separator with `cut` and display except the first field. For example:

```bash
$ echo 'log-2023-06-30-082821.txt:2023-06-30 08:30:32.648' | cut -d: -f2-
2023-06-30 08:30:32.648
```

You can also delete up to the first `:` character using `sed 's/^[^:]*://'`

Comment: Ah.  The sed substitution gets a little more complicated than `s/.*://` because that is greedy match up to last `:`.  OP struggles make sense, really.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/^[^:]*://p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing (`-n`).

Match anything from the start of the line that is not a `:` until a `:`, remove it and print the result.